# lingPipe - sentiment analysis

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am using LingPipe for sentiment analysis. I am trying to run example file from LingPipe which is giving error in constructor -

```
class PolarityBasic {
File mPolarityDir;
String[] mCategories;
DynamicLMClassifier mClassifier;

PolarityBasic(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("\nBASIC POLARITY DEMO");
    mPolarityDir = new File("polarity_dir/txt_sentoken");
    System.out.println("\nData Directory=" + mPolarityDir);
    mCategories = mPolarityDir.list();
    int nGram = 8;
    boolean bounded = false;
    mClassifier = new DynamicLMClassifier(mCategories,nGram,bounded); // error..
}
```

// other methods..

}

Creating mClassifier gives error : con not find symbol constructor DynamicLMClassifier(String[],int,boolean)..

I dont know the constructor syntax for this class, I have just added .jar file.

And also in the program I am not able to find where to pass the text to be analysed. Does any one know how to remove this error.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You are not using a current version of the LingPipe tutorial. Please look at the sentiment tutorial at http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/sentiment/read-me.html

Relevant Javadoc is at:

http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/docs/api/com/aliasi/classify/DynamicLMClassifier.html

Comment: I am using latest version 4.1.0 and I have checked the program with previous versions also they also give the same error. DynamicLMClassifier.html javadoc has different definition for constructor then they are using in this example polarityBasic.java from there website which is giving the error.

Comment: Your code for PolarityBasic is using a very old version of the API. Use the current version cited above and you should be fine.



The new constructor is as follows:

       
        mClassifier 
            = DynamicLMClassifier
            .createNGramProcess(mCategories,nGram);